# KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol.superDecoder(forKey:) doesn't work as documentation says

Tags: swift, codable

I have the following JSON returned by my backend:

```
[
   {
      "id":8,
      "title":"Title 1",
      "componentCategoryIcon":{
         "id":34,
         "name":"icon_name_1",
         "type":"IMAGE"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":8,
      "title":"Title 2",
      "componentCategoryIcon":{
         "id":35,
         "name":"icon_name_2",
         "type":"IMAGE"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":8,
      "title":"Title 3",
      "componentCategoryIcon": null
   }
]
```

And the following `Codable` structs:

```
struct ComponentCategory: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let componentCategoryIcon: Image?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        
        self.id = id
        self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        
        let savedComponentCategory = (decoder.userInfo[.savedComponentCategories] as? [ComponentCategory])?.first(where: { $0.id == id })
        

        // (1)
        if let nestedDecoder = try? container.superDecoder(forKey: .componentCategoryIcon) {
            self.componentCategoryIcon = try Image(from: nestedDecoder, savedImage: savedComponentCategory?.componentCategoryIcon)
        } else {
            self.componentCategoryIcon = nil
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Image: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let type: String?
    let path: String?
    
    let downloaded: Bool
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder, savedImage: Image?) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.type = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .type)
        self.path = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .path)
        self.downloaded = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .downloaded) ?? savedImage?.downloaded ?? false
    }
```

Now I noted a behaviour different from documentation for `superDecoder(forKey:)` func. Documentation says:

> Throws
>
> `DecodingError.valueNotFound` if `self` has a null entry for the given key.

During third `ComponentCategory` decoding (`componentCategoryIcon` is `null`), I expected to go to else branch of the (1) `if-else`. Instead I obtain an apparently valid `nestedContainer` and I have an exception in the `Image` init.

Am I misunderstanding `superDecoder(forKey:)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainerprotocol/superdecoder(forkey:))? Or is it wrong?

Comment: The documentation clearly states that `superDecoder` should only be used for decoding the super class of a `Codable` model subclass. Your codable models are `struct`s that have no inheritance relation, so you clearly shouldn't be trying to use that method. What is the issue that you are actually trying to solve here? Please provide a real use case, since with the current example, this seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @DávidPásztor I'm using `superDecoder(forKey:)` because I have to call a custom `init` for `Image` struct. Where I need to pass a `savedImage` optional array as parameter. Is there a different way to achieve it, without using `superDecoder(forKey:)`?

Comment: @Giorgio There are two alternative approaches to what you're doing. A simple one is to pass information along inside of the `Decoder.userInfo` value so you can get that down into `Image.init(from:)` without needing to write your own initializer. Another is to look into [`DecodableWithConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decodablewithconfiguration), which passes in an additional configuration (but is a bit more complex to get set up with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [current implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/11b0dbc4a5f34c6ead400e7a84d1f06f6983bcf2/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/JSONEncoder.swift#L1656) indeed does not throw an error if there is no value for the given key, and instead returns an empty container; the documentation does not match this implementation. It appears that the upcoming `swift-foundation` package also [maintains this behavior](https://github.com/apple/swift-foundation/blob/5388acf1d929865d4df97d3c50e4d08bc4c6bdf0/Sources/FoundationEssentials/JSON/JSONDecoder.swift#L1317), so the documentation stands to get updated.

This is likely worth filing [an issue for](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/new) (whether for a bug fix, or a documentation fix).

In the meantime, you can work around this by checking for the explicit existence of the key you need, and use that as the condition for your if-statement.

---

This being said, like the comments above mention, it seems surprising you would try to use a `superDecoder` for this. You may want to either add information to your question about why you need to do this, or open a new question asking for suggestions on what approach you might want to take instead.

Comment: How can I check for the explicit existence of the key?

Comment: @Giorgio [`KeyedDecodingContainer.contains(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/contains(_:)) can tell you if the key exists (whether or not it is `null`), and then [`KeyedDecodingContainer.decodeNil(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/decodenil(forkey:)) can tell you if the value is `null`. You can check one then the other before you call to `superDecoder(forKey:)` to ensure it won't be empty.